# GNU Parallel, too many input files, Argument list too long

Tags: macos, unix, parallel-processing

I run a command like this on my macbook, using GNU Parallel:

```
parallel "sample operation" ::: samplefolder/*.txt
```

The problem is that I have 20,000 txt files in the `samplefolder`, which cause a `Argument list too long` error.

And there's no such a problem when I tried run the same script on an ubuntu machine.

I tried googling and reading some `man` files, but no luck. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
ls samplefolder | grep \.txt | parallel "sample operation samplefolder/{}"
```

Comment: This will have trouble if some filenames have space in them.

Comment: Why? Have you tried? Please do not assume GNU Parallel is brain dead.

Comment: Correction -- "if filename has newlines in it". GNU parallel reads one argument per line, so space will be OK. Nut if the file name has a newline in it (which is still a valid file name on UNIX) GNU parallel will treat is as multiple file names. And yes, this time I've tested it. :-)

Comment: And that is true. I have been a sysadmin for 15 years. Not once have I seen a file name with newlines in it - unless it was made by me for testing. Unless you have malicious users I will reckon it never happens.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can deal with this on a typical UNIX box (I assume OSX has [`find`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find) and [`xargs`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs) too):

```
# find samplefolder -name \*.txt -print0 | xargs -P 8 -n 1 -0 sample operation
```

Find will print all .txt file names in samplefolder separated by a NUL character. xargs in turn will read this NUL-separated list (`-0`) and for each N files (`-n1` -- for each file in this case) will launch `sample operation path/file.txt` with up to 8 (`-P8`) of them in parallel.

Comment: But my 'sample operation' is actually a very long one which contains several `{}`. I don't know how to properly tweak my command to work with `xargs` and I kept getting `no such a file or directory` error.

Comment: Thanks anyway, you solution may help others. @Ole's answer works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Handle that operation in smaller batches using `-N`, and pipe the input file list rather than giving it on the command line.

For example, expanding on ArtemB's answer, to process in batches of 16 files (warning, this will break with paths containing newlines):

```sh
find samplefolder -type f -name "*.txt" | parallel -N16 "sample operation" {}
```

To tailor the maximum number of arguments you can check `getconf ARG_MAX` in your environment. For example:

```sh
# ~$> getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

given that paths on *nix can typically be 4096 characters, that leaves me free to put 2097152/4096=512 file paths on the command line (excluding the "sample operation" command itself of course).

So something like

```sh
find samplefolder -name "*.txt" | parallel -N500 "sample operation" {}
```

would let me process in batches of 500. Of course, depending on what tool you are running, you may want to experiment and optimize the batch size for speed.

Comment: Rather than saying it will break if there are awkward filenames, you could use find ... -print0 | parallel -0 ...`. Rather than guessing how many filenames might fit on the commandline, you could use `parallel -X ...` and it will work it out for you.

Comment: For me, -X creates batch sizes that are way smaller than what I can get away with if I use -N, and I can't figure out why from the documentation.  -N500 (or whatever) works, though.

Answer (score 0):

just make that sample operation a bash file :
find samplefolder -name *.txt -print0 | xargs -P 8 -n 1 -0  ./run.sh